# how to get system register tpidr_el0 in gdb for the aarch64

Tags: gdb, arm64, thread-local-storage

I want to debug the TLS variable (Thread Local Storage variable) in the gdb.
For the X86, I can the the TCB by command `print $fs_base`.

For the aarch64, the corresponding register is tpidr_el0.
But I can find the command to get the value of this register.

info registers
info registers all

Comment: I found this https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/AArch64-Features.html.
But still can not get tpdir_el0

Answer (score 0):

After updating gdb to ver 14, I can get TCB by `print $tpidr`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).